# Azure powershell issue to create office365 accounts, powershellinternalurl error

Tags: email, exchange, azure, powershell-3.0

I have been using PowerShell to create Office365 accounts for about 5 months. We use Office365 to archive email. The script I was using was working flawlessly. However for over a week or so, the script has failed. Two scripts are used. The first one runs and it connects to the second one.

I have tried several times, but no luck. Keep getting the following error `"the powershellInternalurl must be specified for the current on premises organization"` . It is only an online account, not on premises, non hybrid. I am baffled.

It may be coincidence, Microsoft were fixing exchange online on the day this error occurred. I have spoken to Microsoft and was told scripting is not supported, it is something we do at our own risk. I explained to two exchange experts that the script was initially provided by Microsoft and now they do not support their own script.

The script creates two active users, however only one is a mailbox and the other is a contact, for example; `joe.bloggs_journalarchive@atecheo.onmicrosoft.com` is the mailbox and the contact mail user is `joe.bloggs@atech.co.uk`.

I have looked at the script several times and I do not understand, why it has failed. I can not create the journalarchive mail address using the portal because the portal does not allow that many characters. However I can add the account using the powershell cmdlets and complete the creation using the portal, such as adding the exchange online plan, enabling archiving and litigation.

Hope someone can help. I am happy to share the scripts, they are long.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two Office 365 services?  Microsoft does not support journaling to an Office365 mailbox.  Doing so is actually a violation of the terms of service, so it's odd Microsoft would provide you a solution for making this happen.

On the other hand, if your journaling to a local Exchange Mailbox, this tends to make sense as the mailbox would need to be created locally.  I've never seen this particular error - but it should give you line number in the script of what is triggering.  You can then look at the command is trying to do and connect with, then validate the command.

If the first scenario above is what is truly happening (O365 to O365).   Why not just enable retention rules and protect the content in place with a single subscription?  If it's a licensing issue - see my point about not being supported (and it's the reason they call it out as a violation of terms of service).  You need to look at putting in place a local Exchange server and journal to that or go with a solution like Barracuda that you can journal too (or catch mail inline).

**Edit** 
I should have looked at the date on the post.  I believe journaling was still allowed back in 2015.  However outcome for today is the same - it's not supported.